# Why #force_encoding consumes a lot of memory and doesn't free it?

Tags: ruby

This simple code consumes up to +300MB of memory, and `GC.start` do nothing.

I'm on Windows 32bit, Ruby 2.4.4p296 (2018-03-28 revision 63013) [i386-mingw32]

```
require 'win32/api'

EnumWindows = Win32::API.new('EnumWindows', 'KP', 'L', 'user32')
GetWindowTextW = Win32::API.new('GetWindowTextW', 'LPI', 'I', 'user32')

callback = Win32::API::Callback.new('LP', 'I') do |handle|
    if GetWindowTextW.call(handle, buffer = "\0" * 1024, buffer.length) != 0
        buffer.force_encoding('utf-16LE')
    end
    1
end

3.times do
    1000.times { EnumWindows.call(callback, nil) }
    sleep(1)
    GC.start # Do nothing
end
```

Open your task manager and check the memory.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think GC.start will ever "release" memory. At least this was the case in previous versions. Once you allocate 500mb, the process will reserve 500mb until it dies. The GC will just mark unnecessary objects so that the space occupied by them can be reused for new objects without allocating even more memory.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks! and what about `#force_encoding`?